# An ultrafilter on $\omega_1$ with a nice Fubini product with an ultrafilter on $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters, ultrapowers

Fix an ultrafilter $U$ on $\omega$ (that is, $U$ is an ultrafilter on the Boolean algebra of all subsets of $\omega$).

Let $(f_\alpha \mid \alpha < \omega_1)$ be an increasing sequence in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ w.r.t. the order $<_U$ defined by an ultrafilter $U$, that is, $f <_U g$ iff $\{n < \omega \mid f(n) < g(n)  \} \in U$.

By ["Good limit" of an uncountable sequence of elements of an ultrafilter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391196/good-limit-of-an-uncountable-sequence-of-elements-of-an-ultrafilter/391215#391215), for each $\eta< \omega_1$, we get a ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}_\eta$ on $\omega_1$ such that $\{n< \omega \mid \{\alpha < \omega_1 \mid f_\eta(n) < f_\alpha(n) \} \in \ \mathcal{F}_\eta  \} \in U $.

My question is: Is there an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\omega_1$ such that $\{ \eta < \omega_1 \mid  \{n< \omega \mid \{\alpha < \omega_1 \mid f_\eta(n) < f_\alpha(n) \} \in \ \mathcal{F}  \} \in U  \} \in \mathcal{F}$ ?